# Component constructor and Router life-cycle hooks not triggered when calling router.parent.navigate method from child component in Angular2 routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an application with child routes

Parent component (App component) has 2 routes

```
@RouteConfig([
{ path: '/overview', name: 'Overview', component: OverviewComponent, useAsDefault:true },
{ path: '/messages/...', name: 'Messages', component: MessagesComponent }])
```

MessagesComponent has 2 routes

```
 @RouteConfig([  
    {path:'/inbox',    name: 'Inbox',   component: MessageListComponent, useAsDefault: true}, 
    {path:'/trash', name: 'Trash', component: MessageListComponent, data:{isTrash:true}},])
```

Both routes in MessagesComponent is using the same component MessageListComponent. For the second route 'Trash', I am passing a RouteData {isTrash:true}

MessageListComponent reads the RouteData passed and is set to a public property.

```
 constructor(params: RouteParams, data: RouteData, private _router: Router) {
        console.log('Constructor of MessageList called.');
        this.isTrash = data.get('isTrash');}
```

MessageListComponent template has links which calls a method 'NavigateTo' with the desired route name.

```
<a (click)="navigateTo('Inbox')" href="javascript:;">Inbox</a>
<a (click)="navigateTo('Trash')" href="javascript:;">Trash</a>
```

NavigateTo method in MessageListComponent

```
public navigateTo(route: string) {
        console.log('Method NavigateTo called.')
        this._router.parent.navigate([route]);
}
```

The issue I am facing is the following.

When I call the NavigateTo method from MessageListComponent, neither the constructor nor the router life-cycle hooks are being triggered.

How can I set the public property 'isTrash' in MessageListComponent when routing to '/messages/trash' by calling 'NavigateTo' method from the MessageListComponent itself?

The constructor and the router life-cycle hooks are being triggered as expected when the route '/messages/trash' is directly accessed from the browser or the page is refreshed.

Please find below a plunkr which I have created which shows the above issue.
https://plnkr.co/edit/oT6ZS8cXrDEIUCgqge60

`

Comment: Updated the plunkr with the fix. Implemented CanReuse, routerCanReuse(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) { return false; } in MessageListComponent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the component is shown but the constructor is not called, that means a previously created instance is reused.

Implement [CanReuse](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanReuse-interface.html) by adding the `routerCanReuse()` method to your component

```
routerCanReuse() {
  return false;
}
```

There is also [OnReuse](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/OnReuse-interface.html) which is called when an existing instance is added by the router (instead of the constructor)